# Tkinter multiple command and def

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing a Password code. I need a way to put to commands into one button so that it will destroy the window and get the username and password when I click the login button. I have looked through this site and non of the methods work for me so I need clarity on what I need to do to fix this.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as tm

class LoginFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.label_1 = Label(self, text="Username")
        self.label_2 = Label(self, text="Password")

        self.entry_1 = Entry(self)
        self.entry_2 = Entry(self, show="*")

        self.label_1.grid(row=0, sticky=E)
        self.label_2.grid(row=1, sticky=E)
        self.entry_1.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.entry_2.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.checkbox = Checkbutton(self, text="Keep me logged in")
        self.checkbox.grid(columnspan=2)

        ***def destroy(self):
            self.destroy()
    self.logbtn = Button(self, text="Login", command =  self._login_btn_clickked,)
    self.logbtn.grid(columnspan=2)
    self.pack()
def _login_btn_clickked(self):

    username = self.entry_1.get()
    password = self.entry_2.get()
    if username == "jake" and password == "hey":
        tm.showinfo("Login info", "Welcome Jake")
        master=Tk()
        def login2():
            tm.showinfo("Logging in", "Logging In...")

        b = Button(master, text="Enter GUI", command=login2)
        b.pack()
    else:
        tm.showerror("Login error", "Incorrect username")***




root = Tk()
lf = LoginFrame(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is the indentation `def _login_btn_clickked(self):` misplaced on purpose? You call this method from within the LoginFrame class but it is placed outside it in your code snippet.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking. You say you want to get the username and password, and then destroy the window, so what's stopping you from doing that? You can put any code that you want in `login2`

Comment: SR87 That is miss placed sorry I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never call Tk() more than once in your program. If you need additional windows, use Toplevel().

However, in your case you don't need that either. You are on the right track of destroying the frame, now you just need to initiate a new frame. We can put that logic into a Tk class:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Mainframe(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.frame = FirstFrame(self)
        self.frame.pack()

    def change(self, frame):
        self.frame.pack_forget() # delete currrent frame
        self.frame = frame(self)
        self.frame.pack() # make new frame

class FirstFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)

        master.title("Enter password")
        master.geometry("300x200")

        self.status = tk.Label(self, fg='red')
        self.status.pack()
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text='Enter password')
        lbl.pack()
        self.pwd = tk.Entry(self, show="*")
        self.pwd.pack()
        self.pwd.focus()
        self.pwd.bind('<Return>', self.check)
        btn = tk.Button(self, text="Done", command=self.check)
        btn.pack()
        btn = tk.Button(self, text="Cancel", command=self.quit)
        btn.pack()

    def check(self, event=None):
        if self.pwd.get() == 'password':
            self.master.change(SecondFrame)
        else:
            self.status.config(text="wrong password")

class SecondFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        master.title("Main application")
        master.geometry("600x400")

        lbl = tk.Label(self, text='You made it to the main application')
        lbl.pack()

if __name__=="__main__":
    app=Mainframe()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ok thanks for your help I will try that later and see if it solves it. ^_^